# param 'data' is undefined in transform request of $httpProvider

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, angular-http

I'm tryng to make a request transform using the $httpProvider as this:

```
    angular.module('myApp')
        .config(function ($httpProvider,
                          requestNotificationProvider) {
            $httpProvider
                .defaults
                .transformRequest
                .push(function (data) {
                    requestNotificationProvider
                        .fireRequestStarted(data);
                    return data;
                });
});
```

The requestNotificationProvider is a provider that is supposed to perform some actions, but the point is that on debug, in every ajax request,
the param 'data' is undefined and i want to get info the current ajax request.

It is something wrong with this code?

Comment: if you have `$http.post('/somewhere', {data: {} })` then the `data:{}` will be your data in requestTransformation, are you expecting the actual request and it's headers?

Comment: why you are return the data and not a promise?

Comment: @maurycy yes i expect the actual request, so how i can retrieve the headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transformRequest` can only change the `data` object passed with request, if you need `THE REQUEST` it self then you need to use $http interceptors

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
  return {
   'request': function(config) {
       // same as above
    },

    'response': function(response) {
       // same as above
    }
  };
});
```